# WPF Application running very slow on Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, remoting

We recently migrated from Windows Server 2008 to Windows Server 2016. Our WPF Application (which we access remotely via remote desktop) used to run fast on Windows Server 2008 but same application runs very slow on Windows Server 2016. Not sure what causing application performing poor on Windows Server 2016.

After doing some google search, we changed server power plan to high performance but no change in performance, still very slow.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the process priority for the application in taskmgr?

Comment: It's running on default priority, I didn't change any priority

Comment: WPF is based on DirectX and use Graphics Card hardware. Maybe you can check whether DirectX and Graphics Card driver are installed properly.